# Getting wrong item count after string replacing

Tags: html, ios, swift, replace, tags

I wrote a code which get `xml` data from `rss` feed and then convert the `NSDATA` type to `string` and replace a html tag in the `string` which makes the `xml` readable, then convert it back to `NSDATA` type.

The problem that I'm facing is the count of items before string replacing and after that is different.

Before replacing html tag, xml item count is 388 but after that it's 182

How can I fix this ?

The code with reducing item counts bug :

```
import UIKit

struct Apps {
    var name : String!
    var img : String!
}

class clipsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var tableData = [Apps]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://razavitv.aqr.ir/index/rss/2")
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in        
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String        
            let processedString = (dataString as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<![CDATA[", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]]>", withString: "") as String        
            let data: NSData = processedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)

            //one root element
            let count = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"].all.count
            print(count)

            for var i = 0; i < count; i++ {
                let appName = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][i]["title"].element!.text!
                let appUrl = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][i]["description"]["img"].element!.attributes["src"]

                let ap = Apps(name: appName , img : appUrl)
                self.tableData.append(ap)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }           
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
import UIKit

struct Apps {
    var name : String!
    var img : String!
}

class clipsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var tableData = [Apps]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://razavitv.aqr.ir/index/rss/2")
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in        
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String        
            let processedString = (dataString as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<![CDATA[", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]]>", withString: "") as String        
            let data: NSData = processedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)

            //one root element
            let count = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"].all.count
            print(count)

            for var i = 0; i < count; i++ {
                let appName = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][i]["title"].element!.text!
                let appUrl = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][i]["description"]["img"].element!.attributes["src"]

                let ap = Apps(name: appName , img : appUrl)
                self.tableData.append(ap)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }           
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

**Reason :** You have removed "`<!\[CDATA[`" from beginning, but you have only removed "`]]`" at the end, there will be mismatch in tag because of character '>', so just change "`]]`" to "`]]>`". This will work as per your logic.

Comment: thanks for the tip I missed that. but this fix doesn't solve the problem the count is still 182